# Не отсылается письмо из django

Tags: python, django

Раньше никогда такого не делал, пытаюсь настроить отсылку письма из приложения. Сайт расположен на хостинге, работает, разместил нижеследующий код, но письма не приходят куда надо, сайт продолжает работать, ошибок не выдает.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'abcde@mail.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'aaaaaaaaa'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

send_mail('tt', '11', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['fffffff@mail.ru']
```

Вроде бы, все настройки сделал. Может еще что-то нужно?

Comment: А локально работает?

Comment: Да, на локальном сервере все работает.  Уточнение. Сайт не работает с этим же кодом. 500 Internal Server Error. В журнале ошибок вот это прописывается - End of script output before headers

Comment: Включи debug=True и покажи, что он выводит

Comment: SMTPAuthenticationError at /
(535, b'5.7.0 NEOBHODIM parol prilozheniya https://help.mail.ru/mail/security/protection/external / Application password is REQUIRED'). Насколько понимаю пароль ведь в settings.py EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD указан, он правильный. Видимо, нужно еще один пароль создать для mail.ru. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Создал в mail.ru пароль для внешних приложений. Теперь ошибок никаких не возникает, но писем нет, ни в отправленных, ни полученных

Comment: Перезапустил сайт, возникла ошибка, где написано, что письма воспринимаются как спам, поэтому нужно перейти на форму и заполнить поля. Сделал, жду ответ.